# How to fix the unmapped members?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, automapper, asp.net-core-mvc-2.1

I am building a new project for browsing through movies and giving your opinion for them. Now I am on the administration part and I added functionality for adding a movie but when I try to add a movie the automapper throws exception for unmapped members on the service where I am mapping dto to data model. The members are from the base data model for example the id.

**EDIT**:

I tried to ignore all the members that make this exception, also tried to made a constructor with no arguments but doesn't work.

```
// Initialization
Mapper.Initialize(conf =>
        {
            conf.CreateMap<Movie, MovieDto>();
            conf.CreateMap<MovieDto, Movie>();
            conf.CreateMap<MovieDto, MovieViewModel>();
        });

// Base Data Model
public class DataModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? DeletedOn { get; set; }
}

// Movie Data Model
public class Movie: DataModel
{

    public Movie(string title, double rating, string duration, string type, string description, DateTime releaseDate, string producer)
    {
        this.Title = title;
        this.Rating = rating;
        this.Duration = duration;
        this.Type = type;
        this.Description = description;
        this.ReleaseDate = releaseDate;
        this.Producer = producer;
    }

    // successfully mapped members
}

// Movie DTO
public class MovieDto
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public double Rating { get; set; }

    public string Duration { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    public string Producer { get; set; }
}

 // Add functionality 
 public void AddMovie(MovieDto movie)
 {
      //execption here
      var movieDM = this.mapper.Map<Movie>(movie);

      this.repo.Add(movieDM);

      this.saver.SaveChanges();
 }
```

This is the exception on img: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5ONd.png

Comment: The `Movie` class might need to have a constructor with no arguments.

Comment: I tried it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work by doing the following.
Firstly, since `DataModel` is a base class, I followed automapper's mapping inheritance [(see docs)](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Mapping-inheritance.html).
Then since you are using a mapper instance to map `this.mapper.Map<Movie>(movie)`, the configuration needs to be instance rather than static as well, and I use the `AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection` nuget package for this, which allows registering Automapper with the IoC container.

My configuration looks like this (inside the ConfigureServices method of the Startup class).

```
            services.AddAutoMapper(conf =>
        {
            conf.CreateMap<object, DataModel>()
                .ForMember(d => d.Id, opts => opts.Ignore())
                .ForMember(d => d.CreatedOn, opts => opts.MapFrom(_ => DateTime.Now))
                .ForMember(d => d.ModifiedOn, opts => opts.MapFrom(_ => DateTime.Now))
                .ForMember(d => d.DeletedOn, opts => opts.MapFrom(_ => (DateTime?)null))
                .ForMember(d => d.IsDeleted, opts => opts.MapFrom(_ => false))
                .Include<MovieDto, Movie>();
            conf.CreateMap<Movie, MovieDto>();
            conf.CreateMap<MovieDto, Movie>();
        });
```

Note that I used `CreateMap<object, DataModel>` for the base class mapping and just used hardcoded values for dates there, feel free to adjust to suit your scenario.

After injecting an instance of `IMapper`, I was able to call `this.mapper.Map<Movie>(movie)` successfully.

Hope this sets u off in a good direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify that AutoMapper should not validate that all properties are being mapped. The `MemberList` enum can be used for this when creating the mapping configuration. For example:

```
conf.CreateMap<MovieDto, Movie>(MemberList.None)
```

The error in the screenshot however indicates that another mapping is problematic, the one from `MovieViewModel` to `MovieDto`. I suggest you add a mapping configuration for these types as well:

```
conf.CreateMap<MovieViewModel, MovieDto>(MemberList.None)
```

Comment: I tried yours suggestion but it did not work it throws the same exception.

Comment: @Dimitar the error might be another mapping. Try adding this configuration: `conf.CreateMap<MovieViewModel, MovieDto>(MemberList.None)`. Also see the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you but I tried your suggestion and it does not work again.

Comment: When you say "does not work", are you saying that you get the exact same error?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Profile Instances](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html?highlight=profile#profile-instances).

```
public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<OrderViewModel, Order>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.OrderItem, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.OrderItemViewModel));
        CreateMap<OrderItemViewModel, OrderItem>();
        CreateMap<Order, Order>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.Ignore());

        CreateMap<Movie, MovieDto>();
        CreateMap<MovieDto, Movie>();
    }
}
```

Here is the working demo [AutoMapperProfile](https://github.com/Edward-Zhou/AspNetCore/blob/master/AutoMapperPro/AutoMapperProfile.cs#L11)